# github repo to AWS, simple pipeline for a static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cloudformation

Very beginner coder here. Have a simple static S3 bucket site on AWS. Would like to connect it to my corresponding github repo.

so would behave like: 
commit changes to github repo ---> changes pushed to my s3 bucket

So far, the simplest solution I can find is an AWS quickstart template using webhooks, lambda, Cloudformation, and the ZipDownloadWebHookApi. The Cloudformation template is already giving me rollback errors. [AWS documentation for this linked here.](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-git2s3/doc/git-to-amazon-s3-using-webhooks.pdf)

Is there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread, there are many ways to achieve what you are looking for:

[Best strategy to deploy static site to s3 on github push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530352/best-strategy-to-deploy-static-site-to-s3-on-github-push)

Good Luck